# Can I call a function inside a function?

Tags: vbscript

```
Function foldercheck(Inputfoldername)
    If objFSO.FolderExists(Inputfoldername) = False Then
        WriteLogFileLine logfile, "Folder " & Chr(34) & Inputfoldername & _
            Chr(34) & " does not exists, so exiting the script !" & vbCrLf
        SQuit=1
    Else
        WriteLogFileLine logfile, "Folder " & Chr(34) & Inputfoldername & _
            Chr(34) & " exists" & vbCrLf
    End If
    foldercheck = SQuit
End Function

Function quitscript()
    If SQuit = 1 Then WScript.Quit
End Function

Function FolderExitsornot(Inputfoldername)
    Call foldercheck(Inputfoldername)
    Call quitscript
End Function
```

I have updated my script and now the problem is that everytime a target folder is not present my script quits, whereas my requirement is it should display the log msgs for all the target folders which are not present and then quit the script. That's the reason why I have written 2 functions and then calling them inside one main function.

Comment: The code you posted takes only one target folder (`Inputfoldername`), so it basically already displays the log messages for "all" target folders.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - the `(Inputfoldername)` is being passed from a text file which could have many entries with basically the entire file path.

Comment: You set `SQuit` (apparently a global variable) to 1 whenever a folder is missing. And in the very next step call a function that quits the script as soon as `SQuit` takes the value 1. What did you expect would happen? Of course the script will quit at the first missing folder if you tell it to do so.

Comment: @ansgar wiechers - thanks I realised the wrong code I have written here. I will modify d script n try to execute it.

Answer (score 3):

I think you actually ask for two things:

1. Is it possible to call a function from within a function?
2. Is it possible to define a function within a function?

The answer to the first question is yes. The answer to the second is no - You have to move the function declarations out of the `FolderExitsornot`-function.

Comment: please see the modified script above. but I am not able to achieve the desired results yet.